# Changing default subscription for Login-AzureRmAccount

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

My Azure account has two directories associated with it -- one for production and one for a testing environment. Currently, when I run `Login-AzureRmAccount`, it logs into the production subscription. Is there a setting I can configure on the Azure RM side so that when I run the `Login-AzureRmAccount` PowerShell cmdlet, it automatically logs in to the testing subscription?

I realize I could use `Select-AzureRmSubscription` to change the subscription, but I'm looking for a way to have it automatically default to my preferred subscription without having to run an additional command. (In fact, this is for use with a 3rd party tool, which automates the PowerShell commands, so I have no way to insert additional parameters or the `Select-AzureRmSubscription` call into the flow.)

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no way to change default subscription for ARM unlike ASM's *-default* parameter.

Here's a workaround using Powershell profile:

Test if you have one already:

```
Test-Path $profile
```

if False, create one:

```
New-Item -path $profile -type file –force
```

Then add this to the file:

```
$azureAccountName ="your username"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId "your tenant id" -SubscriptionId "your subscription id"
```

-*Credential* parameter only works with Azure AD tho. If you are using a Microsoft Account you need to remove it and manually login everytime.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. But, as I mentioned in my post, I don't really have control over the commands that are executed here. I need a *server side* (Azure) solution so that the Powershell cmdlets work without additional parameters. Any ideas for that?

Comment: What third party tool are you using?

Comment: VEEAM's Direct Restore to Azure

Answer (score 1):

We can use `select-AzureSubscription -Default -subscriptionname` to set default azure subscription:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Enterprise" -Default
```

Then you can exit the PowerShell and test it, we can use

`Get-AzureSubscription -Current`  to check the default subscription.

```
PS C:> Get-AzureSubscription


SubscriptionId            : 53847abb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361exxa7b15
SubscriptionName          : Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN
Environment               : AzureCloud
DefaultAccount            : jason.ye@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
IsDefault                 : False
IsCurrent                 : False
TenantId                  : 1fcf418e-xxx-4c99-xxxx-d8e1xxf8737a
CurrentStorageAccountName :

SubscriptionId            : 3b4d41fa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-13xx21b3b77d
SubscriptionName          : Visual Studio Enterprise
Environment               : AzureCloud
DefaultAccount            : xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com
IsDefault                 : True
IsCurrent                 : True
TenantId                  : 67752319-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b820ec2377e0
CurrentStorageAccountName :
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason; I did that, but Get-AzureSubscription -Current returns the wrong subscription still. Plus, I'm not sure this will have an impact on the 3rd party tool I'm using (VEEAM)?

Comment: @Dan please wait a moment, about 15mins, then check, it works for me:)

Comment: @Dan sorry for my mistake, we can use select-azuresubscription -default to set default subscription, I had update my answer, please check.

Comment: this works only for ASM. select-azuresubscription and select-azurermsubscription hold different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

After logging into Azure, using e.g. `Connect-AzAccount` in PowerShell (version 7+), or whichever command you use to login, you can use the `Update-AzConfig -DefaultSubscriptionForLogin {}` command in PowerShell to update the default subscription so that in the future, it will always choose your specified default subscription.

Example of changing the default subscription:

```
Update-AzConfig -DefaultSubscriptionForLogin YourSubscriptionNameHere
```

You can check to make sure the default was changed by using the command:

```
az account show --output table
```